# C# - simple operation with double

Tags: c#

I wrote this simple program just to show a little problem I have operating with double.

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            double a = 110.0;
            double b = a / 100.0;
            double c = Math.Round(b, 2);
            if ((c % 0.05) == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Good news!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Bad news!");
        }
   }
}
```

What I am doing wrong, if running the program, on console I see "Bad news!"....
Thank you for your opinion, regards

Comment: That's a floating point error caused by `double`. Use `decimal` instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your hint.

Comment: Neither the quotient `110.0 / 100.0` (mathematically eleven tenths) nor the quantity `0.05` (mathematically one twentieth) can be represented exactly as a finite binary expansion. When you write them out in binary, there is a block of digits (after the [point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point)) that repeats forever. The `double` type will have to truncate this infinite sequence of bits at some point. Therefore, calculations will not be exact.

Answer (score 3):

Double is not accurate, you can't represent all numbers exactly using float/double and this leads to unexpected behavior. So  you need to use decimal:

```
decimal a = 110.0m;
decimal b = a / 100.0m;
decimal c = Math.Round(b, 2);
if ((c % 0.05m) == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Good news!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Bad news!");
```

Output:

```
Good news!
```

> The decimal type has a larger precision than any of the built-in
>   binary floating point types in .NET, although it has a smaller range
>   of potential exponents. Also, many operations which yield surprising
>   results in binary floating point due to inexact representations of the
>   original operands go away in decimal floating point, precisely because
>   many operands are specifically represented in source code as decimals.
>   However, that doesn't mean that all operations suddenly become
>   accurate: a third still isn't exactly representable, for instance. The
>   potential problems are just the same as they are with binary floating
>   point. However, most of the time the decimal type is chosen for
>   quantities like money, where operations will be simple and keep things
>   accurate. (For instance, adding a tax which is specified as a
>   percentage will keep the numbers accurate, assuming they're in a
>   sensible range to start with.) Just be aware of which operations are
>   likely to cause inaccuracy, and which aren't.

Read this [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use breakpoints and debug your code so you can learn how to solve your own problem (some cases). Let's go through your application..

```
    double a = 110.0;
    double b = a / 100.0;
    double c = Math.Round(b, 2); // c = 1.1
    if ((c % 0.05) == 0) // 1.1 % 0.05 = 0.000000000000000027755575615628914 which is not equal to 0.. thus it is false..
        Console.WriteLine("Good news!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Bad news!"); // Ooooh it's false, Bad news!
```

UPDATE:

But if you change to..

```
    double a = 110.0;
    double b = a / 100.0;
    double c = Math.Round(b, 2); // c = 1.1
    if (Math.Round(c % 0.05) == 0) // 1.1 % 0.05 = 0.0 which is equal to 0.. thus it is true..
        Console.WriteLine("Good news!"); // Hurray!
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Bad news!");
```

Also, using the decimal data type as others suggest will yield the same result.

Comment: Thank Ephraim, in fact if a set a break point on 'if' the variable 'c' is equal to = 1.1000000000000001 (this is strange after a Round, or not?), secondly if after the Round function I insert this "double d = c / 0.05 = 22.0", I have no remainder....(?)

Comment: That's weird, I re-evaluated and mines show c is 1.1 nothing more and the result is exactly as I posted above. I get 22.0 for d and it has no remainder.

Answer (score 1):

When working with `float` and `double` avoid using `==` and `!=` comparisons because of *round up* errors, compare with *tolerance*, instead:

```
   ...

   double tolerance = 1e-6;

   // Comparison with tolerance: difference (if any) is less than tolerance
   if (Math.Abs(c % 0.05) < tolerance)
     Console.WriteLine("Good news!");
   else
     Console.WriteLine("Bad news!");
```

Comment: You are right, this is a fine way to turn around, Thx